# Making query-replace-regexp more responsive

Tags: regex, replace, emacs

<kbd>C-h h</kbd>!

It happens quite often to me that I try to <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> a text.  Thus I use `query-replace-regexp` interactively. So I enter the search regex and Emacs asks meekly for the replacement text, when in fact my search regex does not match any text!

Ideally, I would like to be signaled as soon as possible that my regex does not match.

Is there a way out of this?

Comment: You should check out the [visual-regexp](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el/) package! It shows a preview of matchs as well as a preview of the output!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to start with `C-M-s`, for `isearch-forward-regexp`, and interactively enter the regexp.  That way, you'll see that it reaches the first match, and any further matches will be highlighted.  Then, still in isearch mode, type `C-M-%`.  The regexp from the isearch will automatically become the search regexp for the replacement command.